# T-SQL Cast versus Convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

What is the general guidance on when you should use `CAST` versus `CONVERT`? Is there any performance issues related to choosing one versus the other? Is one closer to ANSI-SQL?

Answer (score 394, accepted):

`CONVERT` is SQL Server specific, `CAST` is ANSI.

`CONVERT` is more flexible in that you can format dates etc. Other than that, they are pretty much the same. If you don't care about the extended features, use `CAST`.

EDIT:

As noted by @beruic and @C-F in the comments below, there is possible loss of precision when an implicit conversion is used (that is one where you use neither CAST nor CONVERT). For further information, see [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and in particular this graphic: [SQL Server Data Type Conversion Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/media/cast-and-convert-transact-sql/data-type-conversions.png). With this extra information, the original advice still remains the same. Use CAST where possible.

Comment: Also, I believe there are some numerical conversions where CAST should be used to preserve precision, but I'm having trouble finding a reliable source for this information.

Comment: @beruic You're right, there is info in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx CAST is required to preserve precision when converting between DECIMAL and NUMERIC types.

Comment: @C-F Where do you see this information? I have followed the link, which opens thhe general page on CAST and CONVERT, and the only information regarding precision I can find is about conversion of float values that use scientific notation. Might I be wrong in my initial comment?

Comment: @beruic It's about this picture at the bottom of the article http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC170617.gif Now I think that maybe the precision loss can happen in implicit conversion and doesn't happen when either CAST or CONVERT is used. It's not quite clear...

Comment: @C-F I agree that it is not very clear, and there should definitely be more specific documentation about it, so lets hope Microsoft does this. But well spotted there :)

Comment: @C-F I've added the extra information to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind that CONVERT is a 100% Microsoft proprietary SQL extension, thus you will have a harder time reusing your queries and procedures in 99% of the relational databases. The standard function for converting datatypes in SQL is CAST.

Answer (score 32):

`CONVERT` has a *style* parameter for date to string conversions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Answer (score 20):

To expand on [the above answer](https://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-cast-and-convert/)<sub>[copied by Shakti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624016/2799848)</sub>, I have actually been able to measure a performance difference between the two functions.

I was testing performance of variations of the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077263) and found that the standard deviation and maximum runtimes were larger when using `CAST`.

[image: Runtimes in milliseconds]
<sub>*Times in milliseconds, rounded to nearest 1/300th of a second as per the [precision of the `DateTime` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision)</sub>

Comment: Both appear in the execution plan identically as `CONVERT(tinyint,...,0)` so probably something wrong with your testing  https://dbfiddle.uk/psHeIX_X

Answer (score 18):

CAST is standard SQL, but CONVERT is only for the dialect T-SQL. We have a small advantage for convert in the case of datetime.

With CAST, you indicate the expression and the target type; with CONVERT, there’s a third argument representing the style for the conversion, which is supported for some conversions, like between character strings and date and time values. For example, CONVERT(DATE, '1/2/2012', 101) converts the literal character string to DATE using style 101 representing the United States standard.

Answer (score 11):

Something no one seems to have noted yet is readability.  Having…

```
CONVERT(SomeType,
    SomeReallyLongExpression
    + ThatMayEvenSpan
    + MultipleLines
    )
```

…may be easier to understand than…

```
CAST(SomeReallyLongExpression
    + ThatMayEvenSpan
    + MultipleLines
    AS SomeType
    )
```

Comment: But, I think the CAST is usually more readable. `CAST(Column1 AS int)` is more logical to read than `CONVERT(int, Column1)` even for long expressions

Comment: Given that `CAST` is the standard, I see `CAST` far more often so that's become the 'more readable' version to me

Answer (score 6):

CAST uses ANSI standard. In case of portability, this will work on other platforms.  CONVERT is specific to sql server. But is very strong function. You can specify different styles for dates

Answer (score 4):

You should also not use `CAST` for getting the text of a hash algorithm. `CAST(HASHBYTES('...') AS VARCHAR(32))` is not the same as `CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('...'), 2)`. Without the last parameter, the result would be the same, but not a readable text. As far as I know, You cannot specify that last parameter in `CAST`.