# SQL Convert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a SQL convert statement. I have NetQuanity (masterTable) which is a varchar(15) and I have another table with Purchase price (PO TABLE) which is money. When I try to multiply them in a SQL view is gives me the error:

[image]

Comment: NetQuanity (masterTable) which is a varchar(15) - why? Is there a specific need for storing generaly numeric value as a string?

Comment: What kind of data do you have in your varchar(15) column? `'xyz'`? Is the data convertible to a numeric type?

Comment: The real fix is to fix your structure. Numeric data that you want touse for math calulations shouel never be storedina varchar field. YOu don't want to do expensive conversions every time you need to use the data as it was intended. There are times to refacor datbases and this is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your field is a VARCHAR, you'll need to CAST to the appropriate data type prior to your operation. e.g.

```
CAST(myVarCharField as INT) * myIntField
```

Be forewarned however, if you attempt to CAST this field to a numeric data type and it's not numeric, you'll be in the same boat.

I would recommend using `CAST` over `CONVERT` in your example, for the following reason defined in this SO post:

Related: [T-SQL Cast versus Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using the `CONVERT` function? `CONVERT(money,NetQuantity)`.

Comment: Also, make sure your `varcharcolumn` does not have invalid characters that will break the conversion. In which case you will get something like `Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a data definition problem.
The first thing is to eliminate any non-numeric entries in the master table.

```
SELECT whatever FROM masterTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(NetQuanity)=1
```

The next step is to include this as a sub-query in the calculation.
In this query use CONVERT or CAST to convert the valid quanities to integer.
i.e.

```
CONVERT(INT, NetQuantity)
```