# Alternative for MAX operator on bit fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have table with permissions that has few bit fields. I want to group rows in this table and get result with top permissions.
So with this table:

```
UserId, Permisssion1,Permission2, Permisssion3
```

With this to rows
13,1,0,0
13,0,1,0

I want to get:
13,1,1,0

Problem is that operator MAX doesn't works on bit fields. How to do that in efficient way? (without using CASE)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As simple as...

```
MAX(CAST(Permisssion1 AS tinyint))
```

You don't have many other options...

Comment: I found that using `CONVERT` is [very *slightly* faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert/50841951#50841951) than `CAST`.

Comment: That was useful !