# Are CAST and CONVERT the same in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [T-SQL Cast versus Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert)

What is the major difference between `CAST` and `CONVERT` in SQL cause both performs data type conversion?

Comment: What do you mean with "*in SQ*L"? SQL is a language and the `convert` thing is not a standard SQL function (operator?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CAST and CONVERT have similar functionality. CONVERT is specific to SQL Server, and allows for a greater breadth of flexibility when converting between date and time values, fractional numbers, and monetary signifiers. CAST is the more ANSI-standard of the two functions. Check this blog for examples of using both of those: http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-cast-and-convert.html

Comment: Isn't `CAST` the *only* ANSI-standard of the two functions?

Answer (score 9):

The `convert` function can do more complex conversions, for example converting a `datetime` value into `varchar` using a specific format:

```
convert(varchar(16), dateTimeValue, 120)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about SQL Server.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

> Explicitly converts an expression of one data type to another. **CAST and CONVERT provide similar functionality**.

So yes, they are functionally the same. They just have different syntax that allows for more complex conversions or (subjectively) improved readability.