# How do I sort the Id in ascending order in datagridview

Tags: c#

This is the code i used to sort the Id in ascending order.

```
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from Contact_List order by Id ASC", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

It only sort the first digit of the number

for example i have Id : 1, 11, 2

and this code sort this list into = 1 , 11 , 2

but i want it to sort the list = 1 , 2 , 11

How to do it?

Comment: Save data as number, or convert them to number before sorting. This is not about c# but SQL.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not sorting by the first digit, it's sorting as if the values are text and not numbers.  Text ordering is done lexicographically, so "11" comes before "2" just like "AA" comes before "B".  I'm guessing your `id` column is a text value like `VARCHAR`; it should really be a numeric value like `INT` if you're storing only numbers in it.

In the meantime, you should be able to get the correct behavior -- assuming you're *only* actually storing numeric values, by converting:

```
select * from Contact_List order by CONVERT(INT, Id) ASC
```

Either way, if you have *any* control over the database schema, you should let it do its job and store values with the proper data types.

Comment: What if i have a number is 450.10 ?? which data type should i change to>? It need to show the 0 as well

Comment: I'd suggest you google it.  There is plenty of documentation available to help you choose.

Comment: @Secret To save you time of searching, you could use the numeric data type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkeyy55s(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a varchar field for Id. Cast it as an int and then sort or change your data type in your table.

```
select CAST(Id AS int) from Contact_List order by CAST(Id AS int) ASC
```

Comment: Are you just going to basically copy my answer and hope for the best?

Comment: @roryap still it's a different way then you are doing it. It depends on which one you would like to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919682/are-cast-and-convert-the-same-in-sql