# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ... to data type int

Tags: sql

I created the procedure listed below:

```
CREATE procedure getdata
(
    @ID int,
    @frm varchar(250),
    @to varchar(250)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500)


set @SQL = 'select'
set @SQL = @SQL + ' EmpName, Address, Salary from Emp_Tb where 1=1 '

IF (@ID <> '' and @ID is not null)     
  Begin     
   SET @sql=@sql+' AND Emp_Id_Pk=' +@ID   
  End 
END

print @sql
--execute (@sql)
```

I try to execute it using:

```
**execute getdata 3,'','';**
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'select EmpName,
>   Address, Salary from Emp_Tb where 1=1 AND Emp_Id_Pk=' to data type int

Please help.

Comment: You can also use Convert function if you want to convert the data with style.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a string and an integer.
You need to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) `@ID` as a string.
try:

```
SET @sql=@sql+' AND Emp_Id_Pk=' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 10):

Try Using

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@ID)
```

This is similar to cast but is less expensive(in terms of time consumed)

Comment: That claim is unsubstantiated -- can go either way depending on your own data.  In summing up this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/707433/731081),  `CONVERT` is SQL Server specific, `CAST` is ANSI.  Recommended to use CAST where possible.

Answer (score 2):

I was using a KEY word for one of my columns and I solved it with `brackets []`

Comment: How can i implement it in my code can you give me example

Answer (score 2):

don't use string concatenation to produce sql, you can use `sp_executesql` system stored prcedure to execute sql statement with parameters

```
create procedure getdata @ID int, @frm varchar(250), @to varchar(250) as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max), @paramDefs nvarchar(max);

    set nocount on;

    set @sql = N'select EmpName, Address, Salary from Emp_Tb where @id is null or Emp_Id_Pk = @id';
    set @paramDefs = N'@id int';
    execute sp_executesql @sql, @paramDefs, @id = @ID;
end
```

see [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

I use the latest version of SSMS or sql server management studio. I have a SQL script (in query editor) which has about 100 lines of code. This is error I got in the query:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'abcd' to data type int.
```

**Solution** - I had seen this kind of error before when I forgot to enclose a number (in varchar column) in single quotes.

As an aside, the error message is misleading. The actual error on line number 70 in the query editor and not line 2 as the error says!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used a where clause which looked at a nvarchar field but didn't use single quotes.

My invalid SQL query looked like this:

```
SELECT * FROM RandomTable WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM RandomTable WHERE [Number] = 13028533)
```

This didn't work since the Number column had the data type nvarchar. It wasn't an int as I first thought.

I changed it to:

```
SELECT * FROM RandomTable WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM RandomTable WHERE [Number] = '13028533')
```

And it worked.