# Trying to display a combination of String MM + int DD + int YYYY in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting

I am trying to display a combination of String MM + int DD + int YYYY 
in SQL Management Studio. However, i encountered an error like this which says

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'November ' to data type int.
```

My codes are:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, Check_in_date) + ' ' + DAY(Check_in_date) + ' ' +
YEAR(Check_in_date)     
FROM Book_Details
```

Afterwards, i tried casting the Check_in_date into a varchar but encountered an error as well. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a string and an integer.
 You need to cast @ID as a string.
 try:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, Check_in_date) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(Check_in_date) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ' ' +
CAST(YEAR(Check_in_date)  AS NVARCHAR(4))     
FROM Book_Details
```

if you don't like the space, you may use LTRIM to remove the space

Refer : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655110/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-nvarchar-value-to-data-type-int)

---

UPDATED on year part