# Conversion Of Datatype

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I am getting a error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UDAYA' to data type int." I tried to sort it out by adding Convert.ToInt32(); but it didn't worked out.
My Code looks like

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("select MenuId from MenuPermissionTable where UserId=@UserId"), connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId",Login.userid_string);
        Convert.ToString("@UserId");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: It is an sql error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ... to data type int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655110/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-nvarchar-value-to-data-type-int)

Comment: may be your `UserId` in table is of `int` type, and the value you are passing in `@UserId` parameter is not `int` type.  Looks like `Login.userid_string` has value `UDAYA` which can't be converted to `int`

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `Convert.ToString("@UserId");`? You're not assigning it to a variable and even if you did you're trying to [convert a string to another string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToString_System_String_).

Comment: What is the value of `Login.userid_string`?

Comment: use exec sp_help 'MenuPermissionTable' in your database. Check what is the type of the column UserId. If that is int, then you cant pass a string to it. I would suggest you should get the userId from Udaya and pass to this query

Answer (score 0):

The error caused by `"@UserId"` parameter failed in Database transformation.

I would use the `Add` method instead of `AddWithValue` method

because `Add` method  can set your parameter Type and size in Database

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int,0).Value = Login.userid_string;
```

**NOTE**

Try to set a correctly enum `SqlDbType` value be the parameter, which as same as your this parameter type.