# How to convert int to decimal procedure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this proc

```
[...]
BEGIN
  SELECT ODMI.VLR_LABOR AS Labor,
         O.ID_ODM AS IdODM,
    FROM ODM O
    JOIN ODM_AREA_IMPACTO ODMI ON ODMI.ID_ODM = O.ID_ODM
    JOIN AREA A ON A.ID_AREA = ODMI.ID_AREA
   WHERE O.ID_ODM = xx

END
```

`Labor` is a decimal in c# code. 
How to convert `ODMI.VLR_LABOR` to deicmal at the time of execution of the procedure.

I try `CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,4), height/10.0) AS HeightDecimal` but not success.

Comment: it seems that the comma after  `AS IdODM,` should be removed.

Comment: Where possible you should consider using CAST over CONVERT.  See this question for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use variable `height` but it doesn't exist in your code. Try this:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,4), CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,4), ODMI.VLR_LABOR)/10.0) AS Labor
         O.ID_ODM AS IdODM
    FROM ODM O
    JOIN ODM_AREA_IMPACTO ODMI ON ODMI.ID_ODM = O.ID_ODM
    JOIN AREA A ON A.ID_AREA = ODMI.ID_AREA
   WHERE O.ID_ODM = xx

END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    CAST(ODMI.VLR_LABOR * 1. / 10 AS DECIMAL(18,4)) AS Labor,
    O.ID_ODM AS IdODM
FROM ODM O
JOIN ODM_AREA_IMPACTO ODMI ON ODMI.ID_ODM = O.ID_ODM
JOIN AREA A ON A.ID_AREA = ODMI.ID_AREA
WHERE O.ID_ODM = xx
```