# concatenate a zero onto sql server select value shows 4 digits still and not 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have zip codes that on import didn't have zero from excel file.  So I was doing a select in order to concatenate 0 to front of every 4 digit zip code.

I was trying this,  but it still spits out 4 digits

```
   (0 + [ZIP]) as 'fullzip'
```

ZIP is a float in db table

my full sql

```
SELECT
    TOP 1000
   [ZIP]
  ,(0 + [ZIP]) as 'fullzip'
  ,[ZIP_Name]
  ,[ZIP_CountyFIPS]
  ,[ZIP_County]
  ,[ZIP_State]
  ,[Utility_Name]
  ,[Holding_Company]
  ,[Utility_ID]
  ,[GAS_LDC_Type]
  ,[ELEC_Non_IOU_Type]
  ,[Percent_of_Overlap]
  ,[Utility_Territory_Type]
FROM
    cc.dbo.ServiceableZipCodes
WHERE
    Len( [ZIP] ) = 4
```

Comment: What is the type of the `Zip` column?

Comment: >ZIP is a float in db table

Comment: Why on earth are zip codes being stored as floats? Using `LEN()` is meaningless then (without implicit conversion), because numbers don't have a "length".

Comment: Oh,  I was given an excel file and i did a import wizard and I noticed the float after the fact ,  thus it was then either build a table first and do a ssis import or just fix the data ... so i was just adding another column of int and going to update into it

Comment: No, don't use an `int` either, instead use a `varchar(10)` instead - because **zip codes are not numbers**, they're digit-strings (like phone numbers). It also allows you to store "ZIP+4" codes (9 digits with a dash) and Canadian postal codes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If zip is a float, I'd convert to char, 
then do the string math.

```
RIGHT( '00000' + CONVERT(varchar(5),ZIP), 5)
```

Doesn't assume minimum values 
of 4 digits.

Comment: If it already has a 5 digit zip code , then it will leave it alone, right?   e.g.   If it is    85226  ,  it is not going to do  085226  , right?   thx

Answer (score 0):

Another option where you can use the implicit conversion (no need to convert)

```
Declare @YourTable table (Zip float)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(12345),
(1234),
(123)

Select right('00000'+left(Zip,5),5)
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
(No column name)
12345
01234
00123
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting *ZIP* to varchar, I would use [cast instead as it is ANSI standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707335/t-sql-cast-versus-convert).

```
SELECT
    TOP 1000
   [ZIP]
  ,ZipCode = CASE WHEN LEN(oa_zip.fullzip) = 4 then '0' + oa_zip.fullzip ELSE oa_zip.fullzip END
  ,[ZIP_Name]
  ,[ZIP_CountyFIPS]
  ,[ZIP_County]
  ,[ZIP_State]
  ,[Utility_Name]
  ,[Holding_Company]
  ,[Utility_ID]
  ,[GAS_LDC_Type]
  ,[ELEC_Non_IOU_Type]
  ,[Percent_of_Overlap]
  ,[Utility_Territory_Type]
FROM
   cc.dbo.ServiceableZipCodes
OUTER APPLY (SELECT fullzip = CAST(ZIP AS VARCHAR)) oa_zip
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using `0` which is an integer literal, not a string value. I suspect that implicit-conversion is converting your zip to an integer and then adding `0` (which is a non-operation), instead of doing string concatenation. To be safe you should use a string literal `'0'` instead of an integer literal `0`, and use the `CONCAT` function to force concatenation instead of implicitly allowing addition instead:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( '0', [Zip] ) AS [FullZip],
    -- etc
```

Comment: `'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`   well - maybe the sql server is too old ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller What compatibility level are you in? `CONCAT` was added in SQL Server 2012 (compatibility level `110`). Alternatively use `+` but explicitly cast all operands to `varchar`/`nvarchar`.

Comment: Where do i find out ?   I can google...   I started at a new company and i think that they have a bunch of old sql server databases

Comment: @JeremyMiller SQL Server Management Studio will tell you what the Compatibility Level of a database is in the Database Properties page. Note that a database's compatibility level is different compared to the sever's version (i.e. compatibility-level is a per-database option, not a per-server option).