# Update sql statement from select on same table with sql server is not giving the right data

Tags: sql, sql-server

So earlier I had a question about adding a 0 to the front of a field when it was 4 digits instead of 5.

The whole point was for me to end up with a select statement to update into the table, into another columns

[concatenate a zero onto sql server select value shows 4 digits still and not 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660583/concatenate-a-zero-onto-sql-server-select-value-shows-4-digits-still-and-not-5/42663883#42663883)

Code that I wrote that I hoped would work, but It ended up just instead doing it is inserting the same data

**fullzip is want the new zip code should look like**

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ZIP],
   right( '00000'+convert( varchar(5),ZIP) , 5) as fullzip
  ,[ZIP_Name]
FROM [CC].[dbo].[ServiceableZipCodes]
```

result of select

```
Zip  fullZip   ZIP_Name
2030   02030    Dover
```

However, my update statement that I created looks like this and it did NOT add the zero  :/

```
  UPDATE t1
  SET t1.ZipCode = right( '00000'+convert( varchar(5),t2.ZIP) , 5)
  FROM ServiceableZipCodes t1 INNER JOIN ServiceableZipCodes t2 on 
  t1.Zip = t2.zip
  WHERE t1.ZIP_Name = t2.ZIP_NAME
```

Now the new column of `ZipCode` that i inserted into from the update , it is only 4 characters

```
 DataTypes
 ZipCode   int
 ZIP  float
```

So it looks like this

```
   ZipCode  Zip   ZIP_Name
   2030       2030    Dover
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing a self-join in your update?  Can you show us sample data from your table?

Comment: I just want to update the same time with the correct zip code , which if it is 4 numbers, then I want to add zero to the front

Comment: An `int` column will never "store" leading zeroes. If you want a numeric *string* that can contain arbitrary digits in any positions and on which you do not intend to perform any mathematical operations, use a `varchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column as varchar(10)  ( in case you have carrier route ) 
You are trying to insert into a column with integer ... not going to work

you want a varchar

So example

```
    ZipCodeFull varchar(10)
```

Notice below  your update statement sql with new column  `ZipCodeFull`

```
     UPDATE t1
     SET t1.ZipCodeFull = right( '00000'+convert( varchar(5),t2.ZIP) , 5)
     FROM ServiceableZipCodes t1 INNER JOIN ServiceableZipCodes t2 on 
     t1.Zip = t2.zip
     WHERE t1.ZIP_Name = t2.ZIP_NAME
```

You should get the right results now

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer datatype should not allow zero in first place
as well as float datatype

for example :

DECLARE @Rate FLOAT
SET @Rate=0125
SELECT @Rate

Output :
125
```

Comment: This would make a great comment but a poor answer. Please edit it to add some content.

Comment: @zohar-peled Of course you're right, but to be fair: It does answer the only question asked :)

Answer (score 0):

If `ZipCode` column in your table is of type `int` then it will remove all the leading zeros. I think this is the case here.

SQLSERVER will not treat '02030' as a number. Better use `varchar` type for `ZipCode` column.

Hope this helps.